# About us page with custom template

Tags: html, blogger, blogs

I am creating a custom google blogger template, I tried adding an about us page but whenever I try to visit "https://mywebsite.com/p/about.html" it shows the same content as home page. Is there any data attribute to render the about page content?
I have been scrambling my brain for 1-2 days and can't seem to find a solution.

```html
<li class='nav-item'>
  <a class='nav-link' href='/p/about.html'>
    <b:class cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl + "p/about.html"' name='active'/>
    <i class='fas fa-user fa-fw me-2'/>
    About Me
    </a>
</li>
```

Also the above snippet is supposed to add active class to that nav-link but it's not working. Can you guys spot my mistake?

Here is my full code.
https://jsfiddle.net/07at4vdc/3/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that /about is another html file and not something like React or Handlebars just try setting the path more clearly.

`<a class='nav-link' href='./main/about.html'>` for example. The ./ should help you navigate to the file